# Ruby with PostgreSQL - Inserting into a JSON field of the database

Tags: ruby, postgresql, hash, insert

I'm trying to insert a ruby hash into Postgres JSON column. Basically its a collection of hash in an array. So you have a structure something like:

```
[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}] #the length goes on
```

The existing code for whatever I'm trying to do is:

```
require 'pg'

freq = 0.05
$test = 0
$sinval = 0
arr = Array.new

@conn = PG.connect(
        :dbname => 'test_db',
        :user => 'abc',
        :port => 6100,
        :host => 'localhost'
        )

while true do
        $test = ($test+freq).round(2)
        $sinval = Math.sin($test*(Math::PI/180)).round(6)
        hash = {:value=>$sinval.to_s}
        arr.push(hash.to_json)
        if(arr.length>=1800)
                @conn.exec("INSERT INTO sinewave(data) VALUES('#{arr}');")
                arr = Array.new
        end
end
```

But now, I'm not being able to store it in the database the way I want. For each row, what I'd like to see is a JSON Array of 1800 objects and the structure be:

```
[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"},{"c":"3"}]
```

I don't know whats wrong. May be `hash = {:value=>$sinval.to_s}` this line is incorrect. Other ways to sort this out?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I didn't receive any error! everything executes fine. however, the data stored in the database is something of form 
"["{\"value\":\"-0.000873\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.001745\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.002618\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.003491\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.004363\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.005236\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.006109\"}", "{\"value\":\"-0.006981\"}"]

Comment: can anybody tell me how do you use html_safe from rails in ruby?

Comment: are you trying to create a single row with all the values? that kinds of defeats the purpose of using a database

Comment: Isn't this what you want? can you just use `JSON.parse` to parse the record and retrieve the original form?

Comment: thats a json column so i don't think it is bad to store an entire json array of objects like that

Comment: @EdmundLee Well I actually wanted the pure json without the \ thing in the database. JSON.parse-ing everytime i fetch records from the database is lame.

Comment: that's quote escape. unavoidable

Comment: and `html_safe`, you use it to indicate the string can be interpreted as html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert hash object into JSON in ruby, it adds escape character automatically so try converting the whole array of object into JSON instead of hash object.

```
require 'pg'

freq = 0.05
$test = 0
$sinval = 0
arr = Array.new

@conn = PG.connect(
        :dbname => 'test_db',
        :user => 'abc',
        :port => 6100,
        :host => 'localhost'
        )

while true do
        $test = ($test+freq).round(2)
        $sinval = Math.sin($test*(Math::PI/180)).round(6)
        hash = {:value=>$sinval.to_s}
        arr.push(hash)
        if(arr.length>=1800)
                @conn.exec("INSERT INTO sinewave(data) VALUES('#{arr.to_json}');")
                arr = Array.new
        end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Postgres persists JSON type as a JSON string. This is a string that you can get by calling `#to_json` on most objects in ruby. Here's a link to how postgres deal with JSON type in more details.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html

Because it's persisted as a JSON string, all the quotes will be escaped. That's why something like this

```
{ a: 1 }
```

will become this

```
"{\"a\":1}"
```

The `\` is for escaping the quote so that it does not end the string.

When you retrieve it from postgres (I personally never used JSON type in PG but I believe it works similarly as `JSON.parse` on this string), you won't see the slashes any more. And the above process is done by postgres.

Comment: storing things with a escape quote in the database doesn't seem like a good practice. Thank you though :) cheers!